# firebase functions retrieve data

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a structure of data like this on firebase

```
-B4PWzQ84KUOeuTuxVY:{

doctorId:2,
Message:abc
}
```

I want to retrieve Message on the basis of StudentId there are so many records 
my code only retrieve whole object but i need only Messages values wherever doctorId is 2

```
   db.ref('students/' )
        .orderByChild("DoctorId")
        .equalTo("2")
        .once('value',(whereresult) => {
        var message = whereresult.val();
 });
```

Comment: DoctorId in your code should be doctorId with a lowercase d

Comment: And the value should be a number. So `db.ref('students/' )
        .orderByChild("doctorId")
        .equalTo(2)
        .once('value',(whereresult) => {
        var message = whereresult.val();`

Answer (score 3):

There are three problems in the code:

1. Property names are case sensitive, so `doctorId` <> `DoctorId`.
2. You store the ID as a number, so should pass a number to `equalTo`.
3. When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

In total:

```
db.ref('students/' )
  .orderByChild("doctorId")
  .equalTo(2)
  .once('value',(snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
          console.log(child.key, child.val());
      });
  });
```